# How do you make an alliance with another faction in Mount and Blade Warband?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I have a right to rule of 74 and have around 1500 renown, but after a faction makes peace with mine a different faction starts war on me. I have a good relation with the 2 out of 4 remaining.

Kergs=34
Nord=21
but
Swadians=-60
Veagirs=-20

I eliminated the Rhodoks ages ago and helped both the Nords and the Kergs take out the Sarrinads.
But the Swadians and Veagirs always start war on me sometimes at the same time and the Nords and Kergs don't go to war as much and when they do it's always with the Swadians who always want peace first and then start war after the peace between us and the Swadians.
Also after peace the Swadians and Veagirs continue to hate me,
my faction owns all the old Rhodok territory (the starter Rhodok territory).

I myself own Jelkala, Yalen, Maras castle, Ibdeles castle, some villages and also a couple more castles. I have most of the old Rhodok lords on my side aswell as 1/4 of Sarrinad lords.

My wife is my minister, and I don't get any send messenger stuff, all I get is an emissinary.
If there is a way, can someone say it in steps? Please, because the Internet won't help me.

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla Warband, there is no real concept of diplomacy. Kingdoms are either at war, in a short truce during which they can't attack again or in a "cold war" which is the default state.
One of the most common mods is "Diplomacy", which adds things like non-aggression pacts or defensive alliances to the game. It is usually bundled with bigger mods.

That said, the game's ultimate goal is to conquer the whole map, either as head of your kingdom or as vassal of another one (though lots of people simply stop before that point), so even if you do sign alliances with someone else it'll be temporary. It's not like a 4X game where long-term, meaningful alliances are a thing.